# Unable to persist state in React Context Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-context

I am just experimenting with react context api and I am unable to persist my state on page reload. Whenever a reload a page my state is set back to being empty.How can I persist the state in my context? I can use localStorage for that but I don't want to token in localStorage as it has something that I don't want to put there(i am talking in context of real application here).
The flow of the application is this
Login=> pass an object to => Context provider(through call back function)=> User(get the object through context)=> on page reload I lose the state.

## App Component

...

```
    import React from "react";
    import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import Login from "./login";
    import User from "./user";
    import Context from "../context/context";
    import AppProvider from "../context/provider";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    export default class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <AppProvider>
            <div>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
                <Route path="/user" exact component={User} />
                <Route path="*" component={() => " Not Found"} />
              </Switch>
              ;
            </div>
          </AppProvider>
        );
      }
    }
    
    App.contextType = Context;
```

## Login Component

...

```
    import React from "react";
    import Context from "../context/context";
    import {
      HashRouter as Router,
      Route,
      Switch,
      Link,
      withRouter
    } from "react-router-dom";
    export default class Login extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          object: {
            name: "user",
            age: "15",
            security: "12xy"
          }
        };
        this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
      }
    
      submit() {
        const session = this.context.setObject;
        session(this.state.object);
        this.props.history.push("/user");
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log(this.context);
        return (
          <div className="App">
            Login
            <button onClick={this.submit}>Click me </button>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    Login.contextType = Context;
```

## User component

...

```
    import React from "react";
    import Context from "../context/context";
    
    export default class User extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          user: [
            {
              name: "Johnny",
              job: "Engineer"
            }
          ]
        };
        this.dosubmit = this.dosubmit.bind(this);
      }
    
      componentDidMount() {
        var security = this.context.object.security;
        if (security !== undefined) {
          console.log("security present");
        } else {
          console.log("not present");
        }
      }
    
      dosubmit() {
        localStorage.clear();
        this.props.history.push("/");
      }
      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            {this.state.user.map(({ name, job }) => {
              return (
                <div>
                  <h1> {name}</h1>
                  <h2> {job} </h2>
                  <button onClick={this.dosubmit}>Click for logout </button>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    User.contextType = Context;
```

## Context Provider component

...

```
    import React, { Component, createContext } from "react";
    import Context from "./context";
    
    class AppProvider extends Component {
      state = {
        object: {}
      };
    
      setObject(object) {
        this.setState({ object: object });
      }
    
      componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.object !== prevState.object) {
          localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(this.state.object));
          if (this.state.object !== undefined) {
            this.setState({ object: this.state.object });
          }
        }
      }
    
      render() {
        console.log("Provider", this.state);
        return (
          <Context.Provider
            value={{
              object: this.state.object,
              setObject: this.setObject.bind(this)
            }}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </Context.Provider>
        );
      }
    }
    export default AppProvider; 
...
```

my sample is https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-hertz-tql5e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In order to store token you can make use of cookie, the rest data can be stored in localStorage and retrieved back after a refresh

Comment: isn't there any way that doesn't use localstorage, sessionstorage or cookies?

Comment: :-) you do have to make use of some or the other storage mechanism or make an API call on refresh to fetch the token. In general tokens are stored in cookies